# Is gremlin local variable in match?

Tags: graphql, gremlin, local-variables, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

I am making graphql api server with tinkerpop3 graph database (aws neptune)
for example, I want implementation of graphql below

```
{
    post {
        id
        title,
        comments {
            id
        }
    }
}
```

and I make gremlin query like below

```
g.V().hasLabel('post').match(
    __.id().as('id'),
    __.values('title').as('title'),
    __.union(
        out('has_comment').match(
            __.id().as('id')
        ).select('id')
    ).fold().as('comments')
).select('id', 'title', 'comments')
```

but this query isn't working correctly. because `id` of comment is overlap with `id` of post.

I want use `.as('id')` locally in match statement.
is there any solution?

Comment: Related: 
[Understanding Scopes in Gremlin](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/gremlin-users/YinzjlEv4-g/5NwynAtnBgAJ) from the official TinkerPop/Gremlin users mailing list

Comment: Also, Netflix experimented on a GraphQL to Gremlin mapping: https://github.com/jkschneider/graphql-gremlin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you @jbmusso

I solved problem using `Map Scope`.
fixed gremlin query is blow, it is perfect form for GraphQL. not necessary post process.

```
g.V().hasLabel('post').project('id', 'title', 'comments')
    .by(__.id())
    .by(__.values('title'))
    .by(__.out('has_comment').project('id')
        by(__.id()).fold()
    )
    .toList()
```

Comment: You can strip out all `__.` for anonymous traversals unless you are using a reserved keyword in the target language (for example, `id()` would be equivalent to `__.id()` here). See the warning here: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/reference/#gremlin-groovy